# Cannot start groovy application with spring cli command

Tags: java, spring, groovy

I downloaded and installed the latest version of spring cli (1.5.1), i created a groovy file with *@RestController* and *@RequestMapping* but when i try to run it i have these errors.

```
startup failed:
General error during conversion:  org.eclipse.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: Failed to collect dependencies at org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-templates:jar:2.4.7

org.springframework.boot.cli.compiler.grape.DependencyResolutionFailedException: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: Failed to collect dependencies at org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-templates:jar:2.4.7
    at org.springframework.boot.cli.compiler.grape.AetherGrapeEngine.resolve(AetherGrapeEngine.java:322)
    at org.springframework.boot.cli.compiler.grape.AetherGrapeEngine.grab(AetherGrapeEngine.java:127)
    at groovy.grape.Grape.grab(Grape.java:167)
    at groovy.grape.GrabAnnotationTransformation.visit(GrabAnnotationTransformation.java:378)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformationVisitor$3.call(ASTTransformationVisitor.java:321)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:931)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:593)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:569)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:546)
    at org.springframework.boot.cli.compiler.GroovyCompiler.compile(GroovyCompiler.java:205)
    at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.run.SpringApplicationRunner.compile(SpringApplicationRunner.java:129)
    at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.run.SpringApplicationRunner.compileAndRun(SpringApplicationRunner.java:101)
    at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.run.RunCommand$RunOptionHandler.run(RunCommand.java:111)
    at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.options.OptionHandler.run(OptionHandler.java:84)
    at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.OptionParsingCommand.run(OptionParsingCommand.java:54)
    at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.CommandRunner.run(CommandRunner.java:219)
    at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.CommandRunner.runAndHandleErrors(CommandRunner.java:171)
    at org.springframework.boot.cli.SpringCli.main(SpringCli.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: Failed to collect dependencies at org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-templates:jar:2.4.7
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:380)
    at org.springframework.boot.cli.compiler.grape.AetherGrapeEngine.resolve(AetherGrapeEngine.java:317)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.collection.DependencyCollectionException: Failed to collect dependencies at org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-templates:jar:2.4.7
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:291)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:341)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-templates:jar:2.4.7
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:335)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.resolveCachedArtifactDescriptor(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:535)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.getArtifactDescriptorResult(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:519)...
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-templates:pom:2.4.7 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/): Connect to repo1.maven.org:80 timed out
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:223)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:320)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-templates:pom:2.4.7 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/): Connect to repo1.maven.org:80 timed out
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ArtifactTransportListener.transferFailed(ArtifactTransportListener.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:355)
    at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:581)...
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:520)...
    ... 37 more...
```

I read to run it a couple of times and it should work but it doesn't.

Comment: Assuming it's just a small example, please also add your groovy file (or the minimal failing example) to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Its most likely due to network or proxy related issue. Please follow the link
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/cli-maven-settings.html
Also you should set **JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS** env variable:
-Dhttp.proxyHost=YOUR_PROXY_HOST -Dhttp.proxyPort=YOUR_PROXY_PORT -Dhttps.proxySet=true